# How do I replace the last character and insert a character to the beginning of a string?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Say I have a text file as follows:

```
accio.
aguamenti.
alohomora.
aparecium.
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
-accio!
-aguamenti!
-alohomora!
-aparecium!
```

This is what I've tried:

```
sed 's/.*[a-z]/-&!/g'
```

Which yields:

```
-accio!.
-alohomora!.
```

Which is pretty close but clearly not what I need. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group to exclude the character at the end:

```
$ sed  's/^\(.*\)\.$/-\1!/' file
```

Or do it in two steps:

```
$ sed  -e 's/\.$/!/' -e 's/.*/-&/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

```
$ sed 's/^/-/;s/.$/!/' infile
-accio!
-aguamenti!
-alohomora!
-aparecium!
```

The first command "replaces" the beginning of each line with `-`, effectively inserting it; the second command replaces the last character with `!`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capturing group:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*).$/-\1!/' file

-accio!
-aguamenti!
-alohomora!
-aparecium!
```

If your line contains only lowercase English letters before last letter as in your question then you may also use:

```
sed -E 's/^([a-z]+).*$/-\1!/' file
```